# C how to use structs and malloc with variable input

Tags: c, struct, malloc

My problem has changed, I need so sort my list of dates but having problems with it not sorting years and months properly. If I comment out and just sort by days it works fine.

Input n (1<=n<=10000) and then followed by n lines. Each line corresponds to a valid date, consisting of one string ("January", "February", ..., or "December"), one integer between 1 and 31, and one two digit integer representing the year (from 90 to 99, and then from 00 to 12). You do not have to worry about date validation. All dates in the input are valid dates.
Please use structures to store the dates. Please use malloc to dynamically allocate just enough space for n structures. You are asked to sort the dates chronologically using the built-in qsort function. Please output the sorted list, one date per line, from most recent date to oldest. Please also use the built-in bsearch function to allow for a user query to check whether a specific date is in the list, and output either "Yes" or "No".

INPUT-
n, the number of dates to sort, followed by n dates, followed by a user query in format day month year (e.g. “1 1 00” or “31 3 68”).
(Note this is a different format as the rest of the dates are presented in)

OUTPUT-
Sorted list of dates, followed by “Yes” or “No” to indicate whether the query date input by the user (e.g. 1 1 00 day month year) is in the list.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MIN_SIZE 0
#define MAX_SIZE 100
#define MAX_MONTH_STR 9

//Define a struct data type
typedef struct{
char* month;
int day;
int year;
int monthnum;
}date;

 //Method to allocate memory for a list of date structures
date* allocateStruct(int size){

//Declaration of variables
date *datearray;
int i;

//Allocate memory for rows (to store 'size' many pointers to 'date' struct data type)
datearray = malloc(size*sizeof(date));

//For-loop to allocate memory for columns (to store 'size' many integers, and initialize them to zero)
for (i=0; i<size; i++){
    datearray[i].month = calloc(MAX_MONTH_STR,sizeof(char));
    datearray[i].day = 0;
    datearray[i].year = 0;

    }
return datearray;
}

int compare(const void *s1, const void *s2){
   date *date1 = ( date *)s1;
   date *date2 = ( date *)s2;

  //if year not equal sort year
if (date2->year != date1->year){
    int year2 = date2->year;
    int year1 = date2->year;
    if (year1<14){
        year1 = year1+100;
    }
    if (year2<14){
        year2 = year2+100;
    }
    int yearcompare = year2 - year1;
    return -yearcompare;
}
else if (date2->monthnum != date1->monthnum){
    //else if month not equal sort month
    int monthcompare = date2->monthnum - date1->monthnum;
    return -monthcompare;
}
else if (date2->day != date1->day){
    //else sort day
    int daycompare = date2->day - date1->day;
    return -daycompare;
    }
}
    //  if (daycompare == 0)
//    return date1->id - date2->id;
//  else

 int main(){
//Declaration of variables
int n;
date* date_list;
int i, j, k; //used in loops

//Read input
do{
    //printf("Enter number of dates you want to enter (between 1 and 10000):\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
}
while(n<MIN_SIZE || n>MAX_SIZE);

//ALLOCATE MEMORY
date_list = allocateStruct(n);


//For-loop to store values in 'date_list'
for (i=0; i<n; i++){
    //printf("Enter the date (month day year) in the following format: text number number");
    scanf("%s", date_list[i].month);
    scanf("%d", &date_list[i].day);
    scanf("%d", &date_list[i].year);

    if      (strcmp(date_list[i].month,"January")==0){date_list[i].monthnum=1;}
    else if (strcmp(date_list[i].month,"February")==0){date_list[i].monthnum=2;}
    else if (strcmp(date_list[i].month,"March")==0){date_list[i].monthnum=3;}
    else if (strcmp(date_list[i].month,"April")==0){date_list[i].monthnum=4;}
    else if (strcmp(date_list[i].month,"May")==0){date_list[i].monthnum=5;}
    else if (strcmp(date_list[i].month,"June")==0){date_list[i].monthnum=6;}
    else if (strcmp(date_list[i].month,"July")==0){date_list[i].monthnum=7;}
    else if (strcmp(date_list[i].month,"August")==0){date_list[i].monthnum=8;}
    else if (strcmp(date_list[i].month,"September")==0){date_list[i].monthnum=9;}
    else if (strcmp(date_list[i].month,"October")==0){date_list[i].monthnum=10;}
    else if (strcmp(date_list[i].month,"Novermber")==0){date_list[i].monthnum=11;}
    else if (strcmp(date_list[i].month,"December")==0){date_list[i].monthnum=12;}

}




qsort(date_list, n, sizeof(date), compare);

//Test print
for (i=0; i<n; i++){
    //printf("Enter the date (month day year) in the following format: text number number");
    printf("%s ", date_list[i].month);
    printf("%d ", date_list[i].day);
    printf("%d\n", date_list[i].year);
    printf("%s = %d \n\n", date_list[i].month, date_list[i].monthnum);
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: From where you're learning C? Seems not so trustworthy...

Comment: C is process oriented, not source code line number oriented (i.e., a script)...

Comment: Your code seems to have spilled out of `main` in random directions. You best collect it all back there.

Comment: The question can't be answered since the code doesn't make any sense. You need to study the very basics of program flow before you do anything else.

Comment: I know the code is a mess, i'm just typing things while I try to learn this. I'll be fixing the main once I get it.

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You have the number of dates as the user enter it. So allocate them

```
  ndates = // user input
  struct Date *date = malloc(Ndates * sizeof(struct Date));
```

Then load them in

```
   for(i=0;i<ndates;i++)
   {
       scanf("%d %d %d ", &date[i].month, &date[i].day. &date[i].year);
   }
```

Comment: Where did you get struct Date from? Supposed to be Dates?

Comment: That's a mistake the OP is making. The struct holds only one date, it should not be plural. The array can be "date" or "dates" according to taste.